# Laravel 4 : Can't add new element in a database

Tags: laravel-4

I am new in Laravel 4 framework, I am working on library management project. I get all the data from my DB but I  can't add a new book to my database.

I've created a form to add new books to my database. I get the `Input::get('element')` value from my `store()` method but the create Methode doesn't work . here's my code to save a new book :

`Livre::create(array('titre' => Input::get('titre'),
        'resume'=> Input::get('resume') ));`

and here's my Model :

```
class Livre extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'livre';

}
```

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Comment: Is it working now? I've corrected my answer

Comment: Did my answr help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Model instance by calling:

```
$livre = new Livre;
```

Then add your 'fields':

```
$livre->titre = Input::get('titre');
$livre->resume = Input::get('resume');
```

Then save your new book by calling the `save()` or `push()` method:

```
$livre->save();
```

Or if you'd like to save a model with its relationships, use the `push()` method:

```
$livre->push();
```

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete You should read this and you'll understand why your answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Seems that when you say that create method doesn't work you mean that the record in your DB is created, but it has empty values. This happens when you dont't specify the fields enabled for massive assignment.

By default , the `Eloquent model` has the **guarded** attribute set to a wildcard blocking of mass assignment. To use the code that you showed us, modify your model :

```
class Livre extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'livre';
protected $fillable = array(
   'titre',
   'resume'
);

}
```

You can read more here : [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment)